# Extracting data of indian companies from google search results

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am scraping data of Indian companies, I scraped half of the data from ambitionbox.com
other half i am trying to scrap from google search results but i got stuck here [I am facing problem to extract this piece of information from the search result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8JGF.jpg)
please help !!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from time import sleep
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


s=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)

pages=1
print(f"Scraped Page No-",end=' ')
data={}
while True:
  url=f'https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu&q=tata'
  driver.get(url)
  sleep(2)
  page_source=driver.page_source
  clean=BeautifulSoup(page_source,'html.parser')
  parent1=clean.find_all('div',{'class':'TQc1id hSOk2e rhstc4'})
  parent2=parent1[0].find_all('div',{'class':'wDYxhc'})
  final=parent2[0].find_all('span')
  final=final[0].text
  print(final)
  break


driver.quit()
```

Comment: Google randomizes class names for the very reason of preventing screen scraping. You might want to try their API.

Comment: yeah you are right, i already scrap a little part of data from google search result without using API but thenx i will try

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get Stock Price, you can search tag by text using CSS selector. For example (I've added `hl=en` parameter to URL to get results in english):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:97.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/97.0"
}

url = "https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu&hl=en&q=tata"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, "html.parser")

stock_price = soup.select_one('div:has(> span:-soup-contains("Stock price"))')
print(stock_price.get_text(strip=True, separator=" "))
```

Prints:

```
Stock price : TATAMOTORS (NSE) ₹478.50 -15.95 (-3.23%) Feb 22, 15:30 GMT+5:30 - Disclaimer
```

Comment: is it  not impotent to use headers in it  ? because i it was working fine for me without headers ?

Comment: @AbhishekMishra It might depend on IP address. I couldn't get any meaningful response from the server without setting HTTP headers first.

Comment: and one last thing - this code  is giving me  `Stock price : TATAMOTORS (NSE) ₹478.50 -15.95 (-3.23%) Feb 22, 15:30 GMT+5:30 - Disclaimer` but i just need 478.50 and i have more then 500k of name to scrap ??

Comment: @AbhishekMishra You can use `re` module (Regexp) to parse the string. About the 500k names, I'm not sure - you can use `multiprocessing` module, or asyncio but 500k is a lot...

Comment: yeah i already tried `re` but output was not accurate because it is giving me a list but list slicing will be different for others so i can not set loop on it